# Drag image on canvas

Tags: image, canvas, drag

I'm trying to drag an image around a `canvas` element. Although I've had dragging working, it's not working as I'd quite like.

Basically, the image is always bigger than the canvas element, but the left side of the image within the canvas is not able to further right than the left side of the canvas, likewise the right side is not allowed to go "more right" than the right side of the canvas. Basically, the image is constrained to not show any *blank* canvas space.

The problem with the dragging is that whenever I start to drag the image "pops" back to act as if 0,0 is from the mouse location, whereas I actually want to move the image from the current position.

```
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if(mouseIsDown) {
        var mouseCoords = getMouseCoords(e);
        offset_x += ((mouseCoords.x - canvas.offsetLeft) - myNewX);
        offset_y += ((mouseCoords.y - canvas.offsetTop) - myNewY);

        draw(offset_x, offset_y);

        // offset_x = ((mouseCoords.x - canvas.offsetLeft) - myNewX);
        // offset_y = ((mouseCoords.y - canvas.offsetTop) - myNewY);

        // offset_x = (mouseCoords.x - canvas.offsetLeft) - myNewX;
        // offset_y = (mouseCoords.y - canvas.offsetTop) - myNewY;

        offset_x = prevX;
        offset_y = prevY;
    }

    /*if(mouseIsDown) {
        var mouseCoords = getMouseCoords(e);
        var tX = (mouseCoords.x - canvas.offsetLeft);
        var tY = (mouseCoords.y - canvas.offsetTop);

        var deltaX = tX - prevX;
        var deltaY = tY - prevY;

        x += deltaX;
        y += deltaY;

        prevX = x;
        prevY = y;

        draw(x, y);
    }*/
};
```

Is what I have now, where I kind of get a parallelex effect.

Comment: If I copy paste this into jsfiddle will it recreate the behavior? If not, plz put the full code on jsfiddle.net, or at least a minimal example.

Comment: Why do you have code that's commented out? You should remove that to not confuse anyone. Also, what is myNewX/myNewY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to record the current offset of the image as it is moved and use that (in addition to the offset from the top left of the canvas) with each mousedown to determine your initial offset.

```
var dragging = false,
    imageOffset = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    mousePosition;

function dragImage(coords) {
    imageOffset.x += mousePosition.x - coords.x;
    imageOffset.y += mousePosition.y - coords.y;

    // constrain coordinates to keep the image visible in the canvas
    imageOffset.x = Math.min(0, Math.max(imageOffset.x, canvas.width - imageWidth));
    imageOffset.y = Math.min(0, Math.max(imageOffset.y, canvas.height - imageHeight));

    mousePosition = coords;
}

function drawImage() {
    // draw at the position recorded in imageOffset
    // don't forget to clear the canvas before drawing
}

function getMouseCoords(e) {
    // return the position of the mouse relative to the top left of the canvas
}

canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    dragging = true;
    mousePosition = getMouseCoords(e);
};
document.onmouseup = function() {
    dragging = false;
};
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if(dragging) dragImage(getMouseCoords(e));
};
```

You should probably treat this as pseudocode as I haven't tested it in any way...  ;-)